# Why can't I get my compiled code to run on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, iis

I've built a web server at home to host my gaming site which I used to pay too much to host with a hosting company.

The Windows 2012 R2 server is all set up - with everything I needed to run the code created many years back. All version of .NET, SQL, IIS, SSMS, VS etc. are same as previous server. SSL cert is installed, everything seems to be installed properly regarding server stuff.

I cannot run my compiled code on IIS! I have the folders set up the same as previous server, yet when I run the site in IIS, I get 'This site can’t be reached".

I can run a simple html page in IIS, but can't run my compiled code which connects to the database. (.net, .asp, C#)

Any advise would be appreciated as I have hundreds of players waiting on the site to come back online.

Comment: Seems more like an IT / Infrastructure problem than anything else?

Comment: "I can run a simple html page in IIS, but can't run my compiled code which connects to the database. (.net, .asp, C#)" indicates that you need to edit the question to include at least two screen shots (with URLs) to prove that. You can simply typed wrong URLs and then things are expected to happen.

Comment: I don't type a URL, IIS opens a browser when 'browse website' link it clicked which brings up domain.

Comment: getting this error:  500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: You can enable detailed error messages to get more specific information about the problem, please first click on your website and open the "Error Pages" module, then click "Edit Feature Settings" and select "Detailed Errors".
Alternatively you can try using FRT to view details about the 500 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to share more then what you done so far.

I mean, does the web server show the site up and running?

What happens when you try to say browse the site from IIS?

Say this:

[image]

So, when I try running the above, I get this:

[image]

Ok, so it says I have an issue on line 23.

So, what kind of error messages are you seeing right now?

Are the app pools you defined for that site running?

Why not try publishing a one-page test site with say a simple button that runs some code behind. Does that site + page load?

So, when you say asp.net pages don't work, what kind of error message do you get?

So, it is rather difficult to "guess" what you attempted, and what you done so far.

So, when you try to run that site from IIS, then you should at least see an error message as to why the page does not run.

So, try the above idea, and try running the site on the server, from the server, and do so from IIS.

Then look at what kind of error message you are receiving.

Do you even have the default web site setup and running on IIS?

So, we need some steps and things you attempted already. And we need more information about what kind of error message you are receiving when you attempt to launch the web site from IIS.

Comment: I deleted all the app pools and domains as I had a temp site. Now with everything re-installed I am now seeing a 'good' error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\  THis is a much better error as I may now just need to update my webconfig file, but we will need to see...

Comment: First Off, It seems I can't ANSWER this and close it so...

Comment: Was sort of an easy fix:

I had set up a temp site in IIS which was working (basic html with images). 

Adding that new site with its correct path didn't work (had its own app pool).
They both shared the same ports which is ok as long as one site is running on those ports.

I decided to delete the temp site and its app pool and started from scratch adding the proper site and assigning the ports.

Now the actual site displays!

Sometimes we need to think way out of the box and I'm glad my troubleshooting is really good. Guess I'm a server manager now lol!